# Display a query using CodeIgniter with a condition where only the same ID

Tags: codeigniter

we have 2 tables `tb_kriteria` and `tb_subkriteria` we have to get all the record from `tb_subkriteria` where `id_kriteria` from `tb_kriteria` same with `id_kriteria` in `tb_subkriteria`

[image]

[image]

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use join for this query**

```
function tb_subkriteria_by_tb_kriteria($id_kriteria){
    $this->db->join('tb_kriteria','tb_kriteria.id_kriteria=
    tb_subkriteria.id_kriteria');
    return $this->db->where('tb_subkriteria.id_kriteria',$id_kriteria)->get('tb_subkriteria)->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run a codeigniter join query to get ther result, try the below code to get output**

```
$this->db->select('tb_subkriteria.*');
$this->db->from('tb_subkriteria');
$this->db->join('tb_kriteria', 'tb_kriteria.id_kriteria = tb_subkriteria.id_kriteria'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: actually i start select from tb_kriteria

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to do use `join` and `where`, to fetch your data

```
function get_subkriteria($id_kriteria){
     $id_kriteria = 18;//suppose 
     $this->db->select('tb_subkriteria.*');
     $this->db->from('tb_subkriteria');
     $this->db->join('tb_kriteria', 'tb_kriteria.id_kriteria = tb_subkriteria.id_kriteria');
     $this->db->where('tb_subkriteria.id_kriteria',$id_kriteria); 
     $query = $this->db->get();
     echo $this->db->last_query();die;//to see your executed query
     if($query->num_rows() > 0){
       return $query->result();
     }else{
       return array();
     }
}
```

Comment: actually i start select from tb_kriteria

Comment: ok you can change it but you mentioned `get all the record from tb_subkriteria` that's why I used it in `select`

Answer (score 0):

**use inner join for this query**

```
function getresult($tid){
       $query = $this->db->query("select tb_subkriteria.* from tb_subkriteria inner 
       join tb_kriteria on tb_subkriteria.id_subkriteria=tb_kriteria.id_kriteria);
       return  $query->result_array();      
}
```